# PHP fgetcsv() - make second value as second key

Tags: php, csv

I have a .csv file with list of bank numbers and bank names like this

```
10000000;BBk Berlin
10010010;Postbank Berlin
10010111;SEB Berlin
10010424;Aareal Bank
.......
```

and when I use fgetscv() like this:

```
$filename = bank.csv;

if (file_exists($filename) && $file = fopen($filename, "r")) {
    while( !feof($file) ) {
        print_r(fgetcsv($file));
    }
}
```

This will get me an array with single key like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10000000;BBk Berlin
)
Array
(
    [0] => 10010010;Postbank Berlin
)
Array
(
    [0] => 10010111;SEB Berlin
)
Array
(
    [0] => 10010424;Aareal Bank
)
```

And what i want is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10000000 [1] => BBk Berlin
)
```

So that the bank name is a separate key in array. How can i achieve this? Maybe fgetcsv() is not the right function for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) is the delimiter, so you must set it accordingly

```
fgetcsv($file, 0, ';')
```

Comment: thank you both of you, both answers are right! but you were the first to answer so i will accept it.

Comment: Or even better solution would be to replace all ; with , in that csv file so i don't have to worry about delimiters?? what do you think? At the end of the day the file is called "comma separated values" and not "semi colon separated values" :)

Comment: It really depends on you.. I found both usages in real life.. if you can change it to comma then just do it

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that fgetcsv uses `,` comma as delimiter by default. You need to change it to `;` semicolon. Then you won't need to explode anymore :)

```
function process_csv($file) {

    $file = fopen($file, "r");
    $data = array();

    while (!feof($file)) {
        $data[] = fgetcsv($file,null,';');
    }

    fclose($file);
    return $data;
}
```